# Named event stream with Play 2.5 and server sent events

Tags: scala, server-sent-events, akka-stream, playframework-2.5, eventsource

Default event name/type in server sent event is "message". I am trying to change the event name but it is not working. I am using Play 2.5 and akka streams.

```
(actorRef,sourcePublisher)=  Source
      .actorRef[T](10, OverflowStrategy.fail)
      .toMat(Sink.asPublisher(true))(Keep.both)
      .run()

backsource = Source.fromPublisher[T](sourcePublisher).named("test1")
Ok.chunked(backsource via EventSource.flow)
      .as(ContentTypes.EVENT_STREAM)
```

But it is not changing the event name/type. It is still listening to **message** event rather than **test1**. Please suggest. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by declaring implicit EventNameExtractor . Below is the code:

implicit def pair[E]: EventNameExtractor[E] = EventNameExtractor[E](p => Some(("test1"))).

It worked.

Comment: Abhinav, we are experimenting on SSE using Play/Akka but we face the issue of connection getting closed as soon as we exhaust what we currently have. In your POC, were you able to keep the connection with client alive for long time?

Comment: No.. but browser reestablishes connection once dropped and events will continue to flow. Or you can have some task sending fake data over stream which will keep connection alive.

Comment: Yes Abhinav, we have observed the same that client reconnects. But  when server does not have anything for hours in that case won't it be a overkill. Is that an acceptable solution in industry? 

Secondly, we tried sending dummy data on the connection in attempt to keep it alive. But in that case the browser pops up Aw Snap error.

Comment: Not sure if that is the best approach but it definitely works. Currently i am working on sending heartbeat at regular intervals but no luck. If you figure out a solution to keep connection alive let me know. I will let you know if i will figure out anything.

Comment: So i used keepAlive method and it worked. keepAlive sends heartbeat at regular interval which causes connection to remain active even if there is no data.

Ok.chunked(backsource.keepAlive(50.seconds, ()=>T) via EventSource.flow)
      .as(ContentTypes.EVENT_STREAM)
In my case T is json so i am using keepAlive(50.seconds, ()=>Json.obj("data"->"heartbeat"))

https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/javadsl/Source.html#keepAlive